# Where is TiledMap located in slick-util

Tags: java, graphics, lwjgl, slick2d

It gives me an error when I try to create a TiledMap. there is no import option. The wiki(slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/tiled/TiledMap.html) says it is under org.newdawn.slick.tiled.*; but that apparently doesnt exist anymore. Thanks!

Comment: slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/tiled/TiledMap.html ?

Comment: Yes that is what i am following.

Comment: Seems you can download everything from http://slick.ninjacave.com/ - where is the problem?

Comment: I have everything downloaded and it is part of the build path. TiledMap will not import. IT is not there. Everything else so far is working correctly

Comment: But it is:  lib/slick.jar org/newdawn/slick/tiled/TiledMap.class